# How can I get less whitespace above and below my homepage gallery?

Tags: css, gallery, wrapper, margin, space

Im trying to decrease the space above and below my homepage gallery of my site, or equal to the left and right spacing. The arrows in the attachment show the area i want to decrease.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
#header, #pageWrapper, #footer{
padding: 30px 20px;
margin-bottom:0px!important;}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your html.  People like to see whatcha ya got under the hood.

Comment: its a template based site (squarespace) so there isnt anything i have added. do you want me to rightclick - inspect element, and paste everything?

Comment: well, you didn't state in the question that it was a template/prefab site.  That's pretty pertinent info.

Comment: I have never used squarespace, but generally speaking:

Comment: ack, stupid return key...  1) use firebug.  2) find the element that has too much padding or margin 3) change the css.

Comment: tried, this is over my head

Comment: @JeffDowell I cannot say explicitly unless you post your html and relevant css..

My guess is, you will have to play with the values of either margin-top & margin-bottom or padding-top &padding-bottom of the container or wrapper or whatever which is containing your page's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll give an answer as I get you.

I assume that this image is in the `wrapper`, and the `wrapper` has `padding: 30px 20px;`

so you gave it a white space from the `top` and the `bottom` by `30px`, I guess you should give the wrapper independent attributes which is `padding: 0px 20px;`

Comment: that did it! I added in     
    #pageWrapper{padding: 0px 20px;